# URLs reroutes in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I would like to set up these URL reroutes in Azure:

All calls to:

```
sub.mydomain.com/path/to/appl
```

routes to:

```
someapp.azurewebsites.net/path/to/appl/sub
```

How can I achieve this in Azure?

Note, `sub.mydomain.com` is already purchased.

Comment: for now, we can't do it in Azure, we should  use a third-party domain name registrar.

Comment: based on my knowledge, we should do it in the domain name registrar, use CNAME to map it.

Answer (score 1):

> sub.mydomain.com

For now, Azure DNS does **not** currently support purchasing of domain names.

If you want to purchase domains, you need to use a **third-party** domain name registrar.

Update:

We should do it from the domain name registrar, use **CNAME** map your domain.com to azure `someapp.azurewebsites.net/path/to/appl/sub`.

Comment: The domain name is already bought. I will update my question with this information.

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance

Comment: Thanks. I think the way forward is to use Tomcat's (I am using Azure's WebApp with Tomcat) RewriteRule. I will investigate this.